# How to get values from an arraylist by pressing a button and change icon of button

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, icons, jbutton

I have to create a method called updateIcons(). This should be run when the user chooses the value from 3 different combo boxes. These are getting stored inside an array list called filteredBookings. And also these values are parsed as date format. filteredBookings needs to be inside the method UpdateIcons(),
What i have is a text file with dates stored inside it. If the combo box values match the ones that are inside the Txt file the buttons Icons should change accordingly.

To explain clearly :

inside the text file i have stored 10/05/2019 x 5 and 21/07/2019 x3 ;
In the design there is 5 buttons with a green Icon.
Lets say the user chooses the date 10/05/2019... the buttons should all change icon to red Icon (fully booked).

If the user chooses the date 21 / 07/2019 then 3 of the buttons should change red and the other 2 buttons stay green.

Does any one know what is the best way to do this and some examples?

Comment: `This should be run when the user chooses the value from 3 different combo boxes.` - don't really understand the details of your question, but in general you write code to respond to user events. So when the user selects an item in the combo box you would invoke your required code. This is done by adding an ActionListener to the combo box. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Combo Boxes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) for an example showing how to change an image when an item is selected to get you started.